# D3 transition on bars inside a popup

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I want the bars for D3 charts to load using a smooth animation. To do this, I am using D3 transition. While this method usually works fine for graphs in Web pages, in a popup which is called on click in a Leaflet map; I am not getting the desired results. the bars just load. If I set a very high value for the delay, teh first bar shows up loaded and the other ones are loading very slowly. This is telling me that the animation has already begun on load. I cant make the chart to load using the animation inside the popup.

This is what I want to achieve, example: http://jsfiddle.net/pg77k/10/

This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/Monduiz/rhn11gpk/

The code in my chart where I draw the bar with transition:

```
bar.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 0)
    .attr("height", barHeight - 1)
    .attr("fill", "#9D489A")
    .transition()
    .delay(function (d,i){ return i * 40;})
    .duration(350)
    .attr("width", function(d){return x(d.value);});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `transition` to run in a [popupopen](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-popupopen) callback.

Save the rects:

```
var rects = bar.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 0)
  .attr("height", barHeight - 1)
  .attr("fill", "#9D489A");
```

Later:

```
map.on('popupopen', function(e) {
    rects.transition()
      .delay(function (d,i){ return i * 40;})
      .duration(350)
      .attr("width", function(d){return x(d.value);});
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhn11gpk/22/).